# Way to find data of a sql table with same status for consecutive 3 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a SQL table like Below

```
Code Name    DayStatus  Date
101  John    A          20-May-2018
101  John    A          19-May-2018
101  John    A          18-May-2018
102  Karl    A          20-May-2018
102  Karl    A          19-May-2018
102  Karl    P          18-May-2018
103  Lorem   P          20-May-2018
103  Lorem   A          19-May-2018
103  Lorem   A          18-May-2018
104  Ipsum   A          20-May-2018
104  Ipsum   P          19-May-2018
104  Ipsum   A          18-May-2018
105  Milton  A          20-May-2018
105  Milton  A          19-May-2018
105  Milton  A          18-May-2018
107  Saleh   A          20-May-2018
107  Saleh   A          19-May-2018
107  Saleh   W          18-May-2018
107  Saleh   A          17-May-2018
108  Virat   A          20-May-2018
108  Virat   H          19-May-2018
108  Virat   A          18-May-2018
108  Virat   A          17-May-2018
```

Here "A" stands for Absent, "P" stands for the present, "H" is stand for Holiday, "W" stands for the weak off.

From the table, I need to figure out the employees who are consecutively absent for 3 days and It only calculable when employees today's day status is A(absent).

For virat and saleh it will also count as consecutive Absent.But if P(present) will appear in between consecutive day's then it not count as consecutive absent.

The expected output should be---

```
Code Name    
101  John          
105  Milton          
107  Saleh             
108  Virat
```

Comment: Those values in `Date` column, are they relative to the day of saing data? And what `Day Before Yesterday +1` is supposed to mean? Seems to me like very bad design.

Comment: if I consider the date of today then `Day Before Yesterday +1 is 17th May,2018`.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I have edited the question, please have a look.

Comment: Is date column important...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as
 (
   select *
      -- cumulative Max, returns 0 as long as there's no P status
     ,max(CASE WHEN DayStatus = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      over (partition by code
            order by date desc) as mx
      -- status of the latest date
     ,first_value(DayStatus)
      over (partition by code
            order by date desc) as fv
   from Table1
 )
select code, name, count(*) as absentDays
from cte
where fv = 'A'   -- current status = 'A'
  and mx = 0     -- all rows before the 1st 'P'
group by code, name
having
   -- at least three days absent
   count(*) >= 3;
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1df8a/2)

This can easily be modified to work when there's not a row per code/day calculating date difference between max and min(date)

Comment: Thank you @dnoeth for the answer.It works perfectly.

Comment: I want your help if I want to count all the rows that are generated from this CTE.

Comment: Either move the Select to another CTE and then `Select count(*) from CTE2` to get a singe row or add `count(*) over ()` to the existing Select to get a new column with that count.

Answer (score 4):

Try a query from this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7c124/17)

```
SELECT code, name, count(*) absent_days
FROM (
  SELECT *,
        sum( xx ) over (partition by code order by date ) ss
  FROM (
    SELECT *,
          case when DayStatus = lag(DayStatus) over(partition by code order by Date)
               then 0 else 1
          end as xx
    FROM table1
    WHERE DayStatus not in( 'W','H')
  ) x
) y
WHERE DayStatus = 'A'
GROUP BY code, name, ss
HAVING count(*) >=3
order by code
```

---

```
| code |   name |     absent_days |
|------|--------|-----------------|
|  101 |   John |               3 |
|  105 | Milton |               3 |
|  107 |  Saleh |               3 |
|  108 |  Virat |               3 |
```

---

This version gives a count of days and a beginning date of each period

```
    SELECT code, name, count(*) absent_days, min(date) from_date
    FROM (
      SELECT *,
            sum( xx ) over (partition by code order by date ) ss
      FROM (
        SELECT *,
              case when DayStatus = lag(DayStatus) over(partition by code order by Date)
                   then 0 else 1
              end as xx
        FROM table1
        WHERE DayStatus not in( 'W','H')
      ) x
    ) y
    WHERE DayStatus = 'A'
    GROUP BY code, name, ss
    HAVING count(*) >=3
    order by code

| code |   name | absent_days |            from_date |
|------|--------|-------------|----------------------|
|  101 |   John |           3 | 2018-05-18T00:00:00Z |
|  105 | Milton |           3 | 2018-05-18T00:00:00Z |
|  107 |  Saleh |           3 | 2018-05-17T00:00:00Z |
|  108 |  Virat |           3 | 2018-05-17T00:00:00Z |
```

Comment: Your code is awesome, but one thing is if today's day status is  "P" after that it has 3 consecutive A then the employee should  not present in the list. but it is remaining in the list because it is counting from previous dates. not from today .
[link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/213d3/1) 

At first it will check that today's day status is "A" OR "P" if It is P then it will stop counting of absent of that employee,otherwise if day status is 'A','W','H' then it will continue to count for only last 3 to 5  days from today not more than that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUP BY`with `HAVING` clause and a "conditional aggregate"

e.g.

```
SELECT Code, Name
FROM [table1]
GROUP BY Code, Name
HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN Date BETWEEN CAST( DATEADD( DAY, -2, GETDATE()) AS DATE ) AND CAST( GETDATE() AS DATE ) AND DayStatus <> 'P' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) = 3
```

What the `HAVING` query does:

1. Counts number of records/days between today (inclusive) and 3 days ago.
2. Record is counted only when `DayStatus <> 'P'
3. A name will only be included if 3 days can be counted

Answer (score 2):

The other answers seem so complicated.  I would just use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(daystatus) over (partition by code order by date) as ds_1,
             lag(daystatus, 2) over (partition by code order by date) as ds_2

      from t
     ) t
where daystatus = 'A' and ds_1 = 'A' and ds_2 = 'A';
```

If you just want the names and not the dates:

```
select distinct name, code
from (select t.*,
             lag(daystatus) over (partition by code order by date) as ds_1,
             lag(daystatus, 2) over (partition by code order by date) as ds_2

      from t
     ) t
where daystatus = 'A' and ds_1 = 'A' and ds_2 = 'A';
```

If you want the current day status, then just add `date = current_date` to the outer query.

Comment: This will find any group of three consecutive days with 'A', but *only calculable when employees today's day status is A* implies that it should be based on the latest status being 'A', i.e. currently absent employees.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME='2018-05-20'  --CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)


;with cte
 AS
  (
    SELECT [Code],Name,DayStatus,lag(daystatus) over (partition by code order by date) as ds_1,
         lag(daystatus, 2) over (partition by code order by date) as ds_2,
        lag(daystatus, 3) over (partition by code order by date) as ds_3 
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE [Date]<=@CurrentDate AND [Date]>=DATEADD(d,-3,@CurrentDate)
  )

SELECT [Code],Name FROM cte
WHERE daystatus = 'A' 
and (
     (ds_1 ='A' AND ds_2='A' AND (ds_3 in ('A','W','H') OR ds_3 IS NULL))
        OR
     (ds_1 ='A' AND ds_2 in ('A','W','H') AND ds_3 ='A')
        OR
     (ds_1 in ('A','W','H') AND ds_2='A'  AND ds_3 ='A')
  )
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7c124/42